# C - strcmp() with formatted strings

Tags: c, strcmp

I'm trying to compare a string using strcmp(), but when I'm trying to compare a formatted string, it won't work, e.g:

```
if(strcmp(buffer, ("Number %d", 4)) == 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

How do I compare formatted strings in C?

Comment: There's no such thing as a formatted string in C. You can use `snprintf` to create a string from a format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation `("Number %d", 4)` inside an argument list to a function is a comma operator separating two expressions, the first of which (`"Number %d"`) is evaluated (for its side-effects — only there are no side-effects so a good compiler might warn about that) and the result discarded, and the second of which is evaluated and passed as the argument to the function — `strcmp()`.

The compiler should be complaining about a type mismatch for argument 2 of `strcmp()`; the `4` is not a string that can be passed to `strcmp()`.  If your compiler is not complaining, you need to find out how to make it complain.

This would work:

```
char formatted[32];
snprintf(formatted, sizeof(formatted), "Number %d", 4);
if (strcmp(buffer, formatted)) == 0)
{
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: On good note:: This is what is expected but we don't know what `buffer` contains.